# Crossover of two Lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance, merge

I have 2 lists with tens of thousands of records as follows:

```
list1=[
"c:\\user",
"C:\\Windows\\app\\Prog\\folder2\\folder3",
"C:\\Windows\\app\\Prog\\folder2",
"C:\\Intel\\Profiles\\user3\\se",
"C:\\Win\\add\\folder1"
]

list2=[
"C:\\Win\\add",
"C:\\Windows\\app\\Prog",
"C:\\Intel\\Profiles"
]
```

I need to cross these two lists and put the result in a dictionary list like so:

```
dic=[
  {"k1": "c:\\user","k2": ""},
  {"k1": "C:\\Windows\\app\\Prog\\folder2\\folder3", "k2": "C:\\Windows\\app\\Prog"},
  {"k1": "C:\\Windows\\app\\Prog\\folder2", "k2": "C:\\Windows\\app\\Prog"},
  {"k1": "C:\\Intel\\Profiles\\user3\\se", "k2": "C:\\Intel\\Profiles"}
  {"k1": "C:\\Win\\add\\folder1", "k2": "C:\\Win\\add"}
]
```

I solved it like this, but the execution is very slow because the lists can have hundreds of thousands of records.

```
def mergelists(list1,list2):
   dic=[]
   for i in range(len(list1)):
        fitem1=list1[i]
        result = [element for element in list2 if element in fitem1]
        row = {"k1": fitem1, "k2": result[0]}
        dic.append(row)
   return (dic)
```

how to increase execution speed?

Comment: If I understand what you want (which is not what is happening in the code), you don't care about duplicates, so if you just convert the lists to sets, it should already give you a bit of a boost.

Comment: so if list 2 would have "C:\\Windows\\app\\Prog" and "C:\\Windows\\app\\" which one should match "C:\\Windows\\app\\Prog\\folder2"? They are moth parent folders.

Comment: The list `list2` should contain the empty string as the last element to provide your shown result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious way to speed this up is to change

> ```
> result = [element for element in list2 if element in fitem1]
> row = {"k1": fitem1, "k2": result[0]}
> ```

to

```
result = next(element for element in list2 if element in fitem1)
row = {"k1": fitem1, "k2": result}
```

because currently the code continues to search the whole `list2` for elements that match `fitem1`, even if one has already been found.

The `next` function will return as soon as one element has been found and will skip searching the rest of `list2`.

Comment: Nice. You could also propose to directly build a comprehension instead of repeatedly add items to a list. But this is likely to be the most important improvement...